# Adobe Connect stuck at "connecting..." stage (windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, adobe-connect

When attempting to connect to our Adobe connect server (v7.5) I am getting stuck at "connecting..." stage. When doing the debug here is the output:

```
Player Version: WIN 10,0,42,34

App-Server returned: code:ok, servers=rtmp://connect:1935/_rtmp://localhost:8506/,rtmpt://connect:443/_rtmp:/ /localhost:8506/

ERROR: FMS Server did not return correctly!
```

I used Nmap on the server port TCP 1935 its open and I turned off the windows firewall service on the Windows 7 box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer for those that may be interested. Apparently the Host Mapping within the Connect server must be the same for the connect pro host and the external name (FQDN)

Comment: Other potential causes of being stuck on Connecting...:
Port 1935 is blocked by a firewall or
 it maybe because the user needs to Right Click->Settings and Allow Flash to store information on the computer.

Answer (score 2):

On `localhost:8510/console/` -> Server Settings -> Host Mapping -> Use FQDN and reboot.

Answer (score 1):

The hostnames in the URLs after "servers=..." are the clue you're after. The FMS hostname therein is 'connect'. That won't work unless your host's name is actually 'connect' and that name is resolvable to all potential clients to your system (e.g. you have a purely internal deployment.)

The hosts must be configured in the admin console with their fully qualified domain names so that the RTMP URLs constructed are resolvable by clients (end users.) E.g. 'connect.yourdomain.net' instead of 'connect'.

Comment: Long ago question. But up-vote for trying to assist!

Comment: Yes, mainly trying to add info for others that might have the same Q. Thanks.